# How to paint bitmap only on non-painted pixels?

Tags: android, porter-duff

I have a 32-bit bitmap that I want to draw on a canvas mapped to a 32-bit offscreen bitmap. The offscreen bitmap is usually empty (just created), but sometimes I have already painted some stuff. In this case, I want my painted stuff to remain untouched when I paint this other bitmap.

Hence, if the destination pixel (x,y) is set, I want my call to [drawBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) to **skip** painting its source pixel (x,y).

**Can this be done?**

Comment: You may be able to set a `PorterDuff.Mode` to the `Paint` object you're using to draw the second bitmap. Have a play with the different modes, as I don't recall which one is supposed to do what you're after. :)

Comment: I think I've tried them all by now. Still no success :(

Comment: I think the correct mode would be either `SRC_OVER` or `DST_OVER`, depending on how the drawing is set up. For some visual clues, have a look at this [IBM article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-mer0918/).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Will investigate further :)